# Loop Through JSON, Insert Key/Value Between Objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**UPDATE** - Thanks for all the great answers and incredibly fast response.  I've learned a great deal from the suggested solutions.  I ultimately chose the answer I did because the outcome was exactly as I asked, and I was able to get it working in my application with minimal effort - including the search function.  This site is an invaluable resource for developers.

---

Probably a simple task, but I can't seem to get this working nor find anything on Google.  I am a Javascript novice and complex JSON confuses the hell out of me.  What I am trying to do is make a PhoneGap Application (Phone Directory) for our company.  I'll try to explain my reasoning and illustrate my attempts below.

I have JSON data of all of our employees in the following format:

```
[  
  {  
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Apple",
    "jobtitle":"Engineer"
  },
  {  
    "id":"2",
    "firstname":"Mark",
    "lastname":"Banana",
    "jobtitle":"Artist"
  },
  ... and so on
]
```

The mobile framework (Framework 7) that I am using offers a ["Virtual List"](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/virtual-list.html#.VJl8AcAAA) solution which I need to take advantage of as our directory is fairly large.  The virtual list requires you to know the exact height of each list item, however, you can use a function to set a dynamic height.

What I am trying to do is create "headers" for the alphabetical listing based on their last name.  The JSON data would have to be restructured as such:

```
[  
  {
    "title":"A"
  },
  {  
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Apple",
    "jobtitle":"Engineer"
  },
  {
    "title":"B"
  },
  {  
    "id":"2",
    "firstname":"Mark",
    "lastname":"Banana",
    "jobtitle":"Artist"
  },
  ... and so on
]
```

I've been able to add key/value pairs to existing objects in the data using a for loop:

```
var letter, newLetter;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    newLetter = data[i].lastname.charAt(0);
    if(letter != newLetter) {
        letter = newLetter
        data[i].title = letter;
    }
}
```

This solution changes the JSON, thus outputting a title bar that is connected to the list item (the virtual list only accepts ONE `<li></li>` so the header bar is a div inside that bar):

```
{  
  "id":"1",
  "firstname":"John",
  "lastname":"Apple",
  "jobtitle":"Engineer",
  "title":"A"
},
{  
  "id":"1",
  "firstname":"Mike",
  "lastname":"Apricot",
  "jobtitle":"Engineer",
  "title":""
}
```

This solution worked until I tried implementing a search function to the listing.  When I search, it works as expected but looks broken as the header titles ("A", "B", etc...) are connected to the list items that start the particular alphabetical section.  For this reason, I need to be able to separate the titles from the existing elements and use them for the dynamic height / exclude from search results.

**The question:**  How can I do a for loop that inserts [prepends] a NEW object (title:letter) at the start of a new letter grouping?  If there is a better way, please enlighten me.  As I mentioned, I am a JS novice and I'd love to become more efficient programming web applications.

Comment: Why do you want to use such data structure? Wouldn't it better to have `{"A": [...], "B": [...], ...}`?

Comment: @Ginden,  that sounds to be a good alternative, however I am unsure as to how I would get the dynamic height function working with that structure - [see here](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/virtual-list.html#dynamic-height)

Comment: @Ginden, my thoughts exactly! I would regroup by title too.

Comment: @Phillips126: assuming you have a set height for each title: `{"A": { "height" : "someHeight", "items" : [...] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var items = [  
  { "lastname":"Apple" },
  { "lastname":"Banana" },
  { "lastname":"Box"  },
  { "lastname":"Bump" },
  { "lastname":"Can" },
  { "lastname":"Switch" }
];
  
var lastC = null;  //holds current title
var updated = [];  //where the updated array will live
for( var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
  var val = items[i];  //get current item
  var firstLetter = val.lastname.substr(0,1);  //grab first letter
  if (firstLetter!==lastC) {  //if current title does not match first letter than add new title
    updated.push({title:firstLetter});  //push title
    lastC = firstLetter;  //update heading
  }
  updated.push(val);  //push current index
}
console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, and adding comments to help explain what is going on.  This worked perfectly for every issue I stated in my original post.

Comment: You might just want to do `val.lastname.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()` to make sure they are properly cased.

Comment: I was actually just about to implement this - just realized the search results were case-sensitive.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Well right now you have an array of objects - prefixing the title as its own object may be a bit confusing - a better structure may be:

```
[
  {
    title: "A",
    contacts: [
        {  
            "id":"1",
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Apple",
            "jobtitle":"Engineer",
            "title":"A"
  }
]
```

Given your current structure, you could loop and push:

```
var nameIndexMap = {};
var newContactStructure = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var letter = data[i].lastname.charAt(0);
    if (nameIndexMap.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
        //push to existing
        newContactStructure[nameIndexMap[letter]].contacts.push(data[i])
    } else {
        //Create new
        nameIndexMap[letter] = newContactStructure.length;
        newContactStructure.push({
            title: letter,
            contacts: [
                data[i]
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

`newContactStructure` will now contain your sorted data.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7s50k104/

Comment: This is nice if that is what the 3rd party component expects.

Comment: This is a great alternative, however, the framework is pretty strict and this structure would result in considerably more code/tweaking to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for` loop with [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || data[i-1].lastname[0] !== data[i].lastname[0]) {
        data.splice(i, 0, {title: data[i].lastname[0]});
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Demo**. Check the demo below.

```js
var data = [  
    {"lastname":"Apple"},
    {"lastname":"Banana"},
    {"lastname":"Bob"},
    {"lastname":"Car"},
    {"lastname":"Christ"},
    {"lastname":"Dart"},
    {"lastname":"Dog"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || data[i-1].lastname[0] !== data[i].lastname[0]) {
        data.splice(i, 0, {title: data[i].lastname[0]});
        i++;
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify( data, null, 4 ));
```

Comment: You are right, fixed. It was interesting to do in one simple loop.